# Why sin function in programming language returning strange sin value unlike calculators

Tags: java, trigonometry

I get familiar value of sin in calculator

[image]

When i calculate it in either java program or Google.i am getting strange value like below

[image]

Please anyone let me know how it works and what if i want calculator sin function in my java program?

Comment: Google is giving you the sin of 27.5 **radians** (which is equivalent to 1576 degrees), whereas the calculator is giving you the sin of 27.5 **degrees**.

Comment: duplicate of [Why do trigonometric functions give a seemingly incorrect result?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77585408)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason you're getting different results is because the calculator is giving you the sin of 27.5 **degrees**, whereas Google is giving you the sin of 27.5 **radians** (which is equivalent to 1576 degrees).

To get the same result you'll either have to change the calculator from DEG mode to RAD mode, or convince google to work in degrees somehow.

As for your Java program, which is what we actually care about on this site, Java's built-in [`Math.sin`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sin(double)) and [`Math.cos`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#cos(double)) work in radians. If you wan't to use degrees, you'll have to convert them to radian form. For this you can either use [`Math.toRadians`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toRadians(double)):

```
Math.cos(Math.toRadians(27.5))
```

Or, you can use actual math:

```
Math.sin(27.5 * Math.PI / 180);
```

Answer (score 1):

In your calculator, 27.5 is in degrees.
But for calculator on Google, it's treating 27.5 in radian.
So that's why they have different answers.

1 radian approximately equals 57.2958 degrees.

2π radians equal 360 degrees.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sin(double)) the parameter that `sin` takes is

> an angle, in radians.

Your calculator uses degrees.

To convert degrees to radians you need to multiply by π and divide by 180. For example:

```
double radians = 27.5 * Math.PI / 180;
Math.sin(radians);
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using two different units. One side you have degrees, in the other radians.

It is normal to have different results as you have different inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the calculator input is expected in degrees and google is expected in radians.

Radians are another unit to measure angles.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian

[image]

You can also use google conversion:
https://www.google.co.il/search?q=degrees+to+radians&oq=degrees+to+&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j69i60j0l4.7543j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8