# Math.Sin() gives incorrect value

Tags: math, trigonometry, s

given the following code:

```
double sin = Math.Sin(59.0);
double sin2 = Math.Sin(31.0);
```

first result is 0.64..
second result is -0.4..

if I type the same numbers into my calculator:
sin(59) = 0.86..
sin(31) = 0.51..

what do I do wrong?

Comment: See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45779825/335858)

Comment: sin understands radians, not degrees, so you need to convert degrees to radians before calling sin. Dividing the number of degrees by 360 and multiplying by 2π will do the trick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The same as most programming languages, in S, `Sin` function gets input in Radian. So if you desire to get the sin of `59` degree, you should write `Math.Sin(59.0 * 3.1416/180.0)` (By `3.1416`, I mean PI value).

Comment: Pi is 3.141592653589393...  (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi#Approximate_value_and_digits). Truncating `...59` down to `...5` is a lot more rounding error than rounding up to `...6` if you insist on using that few digits.  (That's significantly less precision than 64-bit double-precision floating point.)

Comment: @PeterCordes good point, thanks.